# How to calculate D-error of (a BIBD) experimental design?

Tags: r, experiment-design

I have been unable to calculate the same d-error of an example **Balanced Incomplete Block Design** (BIBD) from the `AlgDesign` [R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AlgDesign/AlgDesign.pdf).

I ran the example:

```
# A block design for 7 treatments in 7 blocks of size 3. 
BIB<-optBlock(~.,withinData=factor(1:7),blocksizes=rep(3,7))
```

, which has a d-error of `0.08033556` according to `BIB$D`.

I reshaped the design from:

```
BIB.Design.t <- read.table(text="   x1  x2  x3  
    2   4   5   
    1   5   7   
    1   3   4   
    2   3   7   
    1   2   6   
    4   6   7   
    3   5   6   ", header=T)
```

To an occurrence matrix:

```
BIB.Design.O <- read.table(text="   t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6  t7  
0   1   0   1   1   0   0   
1   0   0   0   1   0   1   
1   0   1   1   0   0   0   
0   1   1   0   0   0   1   
1   1   0   0   0   1   0   
0   0   0   1   0   1   1   
0   0   1   0   1   1   0   ", header=T)
```

On page 11 of the AlgDesign documentation, is says the d-error `D` is calculated as:
[image]

Running the syntax below produces an incorrect d-error of `0.3541996`:

```
det(t(BIB.Design.O)%*%BIB.Design.O/7)^(1/7)
```

I've tried to subtract the appropriate block mean from each row of $X$, but then I get `Nan` when trying the calculate the d-error.

How does one actually calculate d-error on a BIBD?